Added extend color doesn't work in TailwindCSS
I'm trying to create a custom color and name it primary but it doesn't seem to work. It works when using other names but it feels like there should be a way to naming it primary? What am I missing?
tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: "red",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};

example.jsx
<nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-primary p-6">
  ...
</nav>


Probably you're using pre-built tailwind.css that's why your changes is not affected, please check your project "style build" scripts under package.json if you're using some kind boilerplate

TailwindCSS must be running to update CSS classes. TailwindCSS CLI: Installation (follow step 4) or TailwindCSS with PostCSS: Installation (follow step 5) or Find your framework instructions here

Maybe  useful for React: className global attribute in React DOM - React Docs; When did React start supporting class attribute in JSX - StackOverflow answer

Working playground. - Like I said, there's nothing wrong with it. This is some basic oversight on your part. Either you haven't installed tailwind, or you're not running it, or you haven't imported it correctly, e.g. the CSS. Need @ tailwind base; @ tailwind components; @ tailwind utilities; lines in your CSS file, otherwise it won't work.

Try this code:


// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          DEFAULT: "red", // For `bg-primary`
          500: "red", // For `bg-primary-500`
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};



I believe in Tailwind CSS, custom colors like primary need to be properly registered and referenced in your classes. The issue you're facing is likely because Tailwind's color classes follow a specific naming convention where you append shade numbers to the color name (like primary-500, primary-700, etc.). If you want to use bg-primary directly, Tailwind doesn't recognize it by default.
